# Gtk::StatusIcon system tray alignment issues

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, gtkmm3

I'm creating a Gtk::StatusIcon object from a PNG file but the system tray icon displays in the center of the system tray.

How can I get this system tray icon alignment over to the right side by default. I've looked at the GTK::StatusIcon API but did not see anything.

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::StatusIcon> m_status_icon;
m_status_icon = Gtk::StatusIcon::create_from_file("icon.png");
```

I'm developing on Ubuntu 18.04 using gtkmm-3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/3.24/classGtk_1_1StatusIcon.html), this does not seem possible  in Gtkmm, or GTK+ (nothing in the API gives you such control). Also, note that `Gtk::StatusIcon` [is deprecated](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/3.24/deprecated.html#_deprecated000788) in favor of plateform specific APIs.